# Chrome extension development: *sometimes* can not inject into activeTab (permissions)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my `manifest.json` among other I have `"permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "contextMenus"]` but despite this *sometimes* after pushing my button in a context menu that inject code to the current tab - in console I see:

`Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.
    at ContextMenusItems.chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener`

Inside `addListener`: `chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: 'contentScript.js'})`.

Once again - *usually* this works, I have not yer grasped the case when this happens.

Google Chrome 59 macOS.

For me it looks like a bug in Chromium.

Comment: You've tried it on a tab with `chrome://` (built-in browser pages) or `chrome-extension://` (extension pages) URLs which isn't supported.

Comment: Or maybe your code exceeded the [user gesture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) context. It may happen if you run something asynchronous like XHR/fetch and then executeScript in the callback.

Comment: I tried on usual pages, but yes frequently after `chrome-extensions://` - maybe Chrome need some additional time to switch the context...

Comment: Switching tabs switches the context immediately so barring an error in your code it cannot cause the issue.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].